Creating a web app to upload files on Android
In order to get around the Salesforce Mobile app only allowing Android users to upload a single picture or file at a time, I created a simple web app that allows multiple files to be uploaded and saved to a record via the files relationship using the Salesforce REST api. The web page is accessed through a URL button on a record page.
My issue is that the user is prompted to sign in as often as the access token needs to be refreshed, which seems to be frequent enough to cause annoyance. Is there a way I can authenticate with oauth2.0 using the credentials the user has saved in the Salesforce Mobile app?
